I'm having trouble figuring out how to save session tokens
I'm not able to send an ID token to my server to establish a session in a Node,js web app with express-session.
I'm able to get the ID token from Firebase Auth after submitting a verification code, but I get an error, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token'),  when the /set-token endpoint request is made in sendTokenToServer().
app.js
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { dirname, join } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import serviceAccount from "../config/serviceAccount.js";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Firebase Admin SDK setup
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

// Middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'your-secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
//   cookie: { secure: false } // Set to true if using HTTPS
  cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } // 1 day
}));
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Auth middleware
const checkAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.body.token;
    if (!token) {
        console.log('No Session token:');
        return res.redirect('/');
    }

    try {
        const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
        console.log('Decoded token:', decodedToken); // Add logging here
        req.user = decodedToken;
    next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error verifying token:', error);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};

app.post('/set-token', (req, res) => {

    // TODO token is undefined here <--------------------------------------------------------<<<

    // const token = req.session.token;

    // The commented line above was changed to get
    // try getting the token from the req.body instead
    // of the req.session (as below, per @doug-stevenson's
    // response to this post), but I still get the
    // same error -- the token isn't received in this
    // function in the req.body or req.session.

    const token = req.body.token;

    req.session.token = token;
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

app.get('/feed', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('feed');
});

app.get('/dashboard', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard');
});

app.get('/post/:id', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('post', { id: req.params.id });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});


login.js
const countryCode = '+1';

document.getElementById('send-code').addEventListener('click', handleSendCode);
document.getElementById('verify-code').addEventListener('click', handleVerifyCode);

function handleSendCode() {
  const phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber();
  const recaptchaVerifier = createRecaptchaVerifier();

  signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier)
    .then(handleConfirmationResult)
    .catch(handleSendCodeError);
}

function getPhoneNumber() {
  return countryCode + document.getElementById('phone-number').value;
}

function createRecaptchaVerifier() {
  return new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
}

function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier) {
  return firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier);
}

function handleConfirmationResult(confirmationResult) {
  window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
  toggleLoginSteps();
}

function toggleLoginSteps() {
  document.getElementById('login-step-1').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('login-step-2').style.display = 'block';
}

function handleSendCodeError(error) {
  console.error('Error sending verification code:', error);
}

function handleVerifyCode() {
  const verificationCode = getVerificationCode();

  confirmVerificationCode(verificationCode)
    .then(handleVerificationSuccess)
    .catch(handleVerificationError);
}

function getVerificationCode() {
  return document.getElementById('verification-code').value;
}

function confirmVerificationCode(verificationCode) {
  return window.confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode);
}

async function handleVerificationSuccess(result) {
  const user = result.user;
  const idToken = await user.getIdToken();

  sendTokenToServer(idToken)
    .then(handleTokenResponse)
    .catch(handleTokenError);
}

function sendTokenToServer(idToken) {
  return fetch('/set-token', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ token: idToken }) // <---------------------------------------------<<<
  });
}

function handleTokenResponse(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    window.location.href = '/feed';
  } else {
    console.error('Failed to set token');
  }
}

function handleTokenError(error) {
  console.error('Error sending token:', error);
}

function handleVerificationError(error) {
  console.error('Error verifying code:', error);
}


I tried to copy the ID token after the user.getIdToken() call and sending the ID token to the /set-token endpoint with Postman and get the same error -- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined.

Your set-token endpoint is reading the token from the client's session cookies:
const token = req.session.token;

That doesn't seem right to me.  The token is being passed as part of the request body, so you should probably read it like this (as you already are in your middleware):
const token = req.body.token;


Thank you for your response.
I tried changing req.session.token to req.body.token in the /set-token endpoint and in the checkAuth function but didn't get a token in either case. I got an error: "No Session token:".

That sounds like a new, different problem that maybe requires a new post with new debugging details about where that error is coming from.

I think it's a new problem if we can get a token in either the /set-endpoint handler or the checkAuth function via either req.session.token or req.body.token. Right now it's not clear why express-session isn't saving the token in either case.

The error message you first posted about ("TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')") is clearly (to me) a matter of not using req.body to find the token coming from the request.  Now that that problem is solved, the new problem something else entirely that needs separate debugging.

This is my fist post, so I'll take your word for it that that's what I need to do.

Please use a middleware to get the request body parsed. The below code shows the same using express.json.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./'));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/token', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.token);
  res.send(req.body.token);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    Token via Body
  </head>
  <body>
    <p></p>
  </body>
  <script>
    const para = document.querySelector('p');
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ token: 'some token' }),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          para.textContent = res.statusText;
        } else {
          return res.text();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        para.textContent = data;
      });
  </script>
</html>

Test and results:
URL : http://localhost:3000

Output in Browser : 
   Token via Body
   some token

Output in server console:
  some token


Hi, Thank you. Is the issue resolved ?

Yes, it is. thanks again.

Glad to hear. As a matter of procedure, request you may please mark your question as closed.  As you know, this will keep the data in this site updated.
